# How to programmatically put an NSObjectController into entity mode?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsobjectcontroller

I'm instantiating an `NSTreeController` programmatically and want to put it into entity mode, but regardless of what I do it sticks to class mode.

The following code fragment doesn't work:

```
    NSTreeController *treeCon       = [[NSTreeController alloc] initWithContent:nil];
    treeCon.entityName              = currentEntityItem.entityDescription.name;
    XaDocument *document            = self.document;
    treeCon.managedObjectContext    = document.managedObjectContext;
    treeCon.objectClass             = nil;
```

Does anyone know how to programmatically put an `NSObjectController` into entity mode?
(I do know how to do this using IB, but I need to instantiate the controller programmatically.)

Comment: See [NSArrayController initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1862665/4244136)

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the link, but adding a fetch doesn't change anything.

Comment: Set `automaticallyPreparesContent` to `YES`?

Comment: It looks like a bug to me, `initWithCoder` sets a `isUsingManagedProxy` flag. I don't know if the missing flag causes any issues. How do you check if `treeCon` is in entity mode? The description in the debugger says class mode but the content looks ok.

Comment: I check `arrangedObjects`.

Comment: Is `arrangedObjects` something like `<_NSControllerTreeProxy: 0x60c00008b680>, child nodes {}`? Try `treeCon.arrangedObjects.childNodes` or `treeCon.content`.

Answer (score 0):

Back then, I solved the problem by instantiating the controller via IB.

Now I came across this problem again for a new project and here's the code that forces an `NSArrayController` into entity mode:

```
    NSArrayController *ac           = NSArrayController.alloc.init;
    ac.entityName                   = <#entity name#>;
    ac.managedObjectContext         = <#context#>;
    [ac fetchWithRequest:nil merge:NO error:nil];
```